# How to reset github access token in git bash ubuntu?

Tags: git, authentication, ubuntu, github

A month ago I changed my OS to Ubuntu and installed Git.

When I had wanted to do some `git` command, terminal asked me for username and password, since the password cannot be used I set up a personal  access token, but now the token is expired.

I cannot do anything with `git` on my computer now, I have tried to change and update my personal access token or password or anything but nothing works.
Please help.

I keep getting this error:

```bash
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for ...
```

I tried:

```
git config --global --unset-all ...
```

And I removed the username and email, but I don't know how to force the git bash to ask me for new password or something.

Comment: I succeded with:gh auth login

Comment: Then either give that as an Answer or delete the question. Note that your solution reflects the key fact: authentication has nothing to do with Git.

Answer (score 0):

While [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) is one way, do check also if your old token was registered in the credential helper:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=you" | git credential-$(git config --global credential.helper) get
```

(replace 'you' by your GitHub account name)

If you see your old token, you can remove it with the [`erase` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-codegetcode).